# react list component responsive using row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
export default (props, index) => {
    const listing = props.listing

    return(
        <div className={4 % index === 0 && 'row'}>
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <h4>{listing.name}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

How to add row to group 4 items in a row? Above is a list item component.

Comment: try this: `<div className={index % 4 === 0 ? 'row' : ''}>`

Comment: @MayankShukla doesn't work at all

Comment: Please expand your answer a bit more. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Explain this grouping that you want.

Comment: Can you explain your problem  better? It is unclear what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here because your question is not really clear.

I'm guessing you have an array of listings and you need 4 listings per row.

This is how that might look:

```
const listingRows = listings.slice(0, 4).map(listing => 
  `<div className='col-md-4'>{listing.name}</div>`
)

return (
  <div class='row'>
  {listingRows}
  </div>
)
```

This will get you the first four elements of your `listing` array in a row.

If you can explain better we might be able to help you better